# How to catch an exception from Azure Mobile App Backend?

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

In my Azure Mobile App backend, I have a validation for the data in a post method. In certains circunstances, the backend server throw an exception, but, in the app side, I can't get catch this exception. How can I do that?

That's my method

```
// POST tables/Paciente
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostPaciente(Paciente novoPaciente)
{   

    //other things

    if (paciente != null)
    {
        var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            Content = new StringContent("Já existe um paciente com esse token cadastrado.")
        };

        //throw new HttpResponseException(responseMessage);
        return InternalServerError(new Exception("Já existe um paciente com esse token cadastrado."));
    }
}
```

I tried throw HttpResponseException and return InternalServerException, but none works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the status code of the response to your http call (there should be a `IsSuccesStatusCode` property to check).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` which exists in the `HttpResponseMessage` class. This method will throw an exception if the `StatusCode` is not `OK` (or some variant of a 200-level status code).

Below is a generic class, `BaseHttpClientServices`, that I use for making REST API requests in all of my projects. It follows all of the best practices for using HttpClient like [Reusing HttpClient](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/), [Deserializing JSON using `Stream`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm), and using [ConfigureAwait(false)](https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f).

## Sending A Post Request in Xamarin.Forms

```cs
public abstract class HttpClientServices : BaseHttpClientServices
{
    const string apiUrl = "your api url";

    public static void PostPaciente(Paciente novoPaciente)
    {    
        try
        {
            var response = await PostObjectToAPI(apiUrl, novoPaciente);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Handle Exception
        }
    }
}
```

## Generic HttpClient Implementation

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace NameSpace
{
    public abstract class BaseHttpClientService
    {
        #region Constant Fields
        static readonly Lazy<JsonSerializer> _serializerHolder = new Lazy<JsonSerializer>();
        static readonly Lazy<HttpClient> _clientHolder = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => CreateHttpClient(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)));
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        static int _networkIndicatorCount = 0;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        static HttpClient Client => _clientHolder.Value;
        static JsonSerializer Serializer => _serializerHolder.Value;
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        protected static async Task<T> GetObjectFromAPI<T>(string apiUrl)
        {
            using (var responseMessage = await GetObjectFromAPI(apiUrl).ConfigureAwait(false))
                return await DeserializeResponse<T>(responseMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        protected static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetObjectFromAPI(string apiUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                UpdateActivityIndicatorStatus(true);

                return await Client.GetAsync(apiUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Report(e);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                UpdateActivityIndicatorStatus(false);
            }
        }

        protected static async Task<TResponse> PostObjectToAPI<TResponse, TRequest>(string apiUrl, TRequest requestData)
        {
            using (var responseMessage = await PostObjectToAPI(apiUrl, requestData).ConfigureAwait(false))
                return await DeserializeResponse<TResponse>(responseMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        protected static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostObjectToAPI<T>(string apiUrl, T requestData) => SendAsync(HttpMethod.Post, apiUrl, requestData);

        protected static async Task<TResponse> PutObjectToAPI<TResponse, TRequest>(string apiUrl, TRequest requestData)
        {
            using (var responseMessage = await PutObjectToAPI(apiUrl, requestData).ConfigureAwait(false))
                return await DeserializeResponse<TResponse>(responseMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        protected static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutObjectToAPI<T>(string apiUrl, T requestData) => SendAsync(HttpMethod.Put, apiUrl, requestData);

        protected static async Task<TResponse> PatchObjectToAPI<TResponse, TRequest>(string apiUrl, TRequest requestData)
        {
            using (var responseMessage = await PatchObjectToAPI(apiUrl, requestData).ConfigureAwait(false))
                return await DeserializeResponse<TResponse>(responseMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        protected static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchObjectToAPI<T>(string apiUrl, T requestData) => SendAsync(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), apiUrl, requestData);

        protected static async Task<TResponse> DeleteObjectFromAPI<TResponse>(string apiUrl)
        {
            using (var responseMessage = await DeleteObjectFromAPI(apiUrl).ConfigureAwait(false))
                return await DeserializeResponse<TResponse>(responseMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        protected static Task<HttpResponseMessage> DeleteObjectFromAPI(string apiUrl) => SendAsync<object>(HttpMethod.Delete, apiUrl);

        static HttpClient CreateHttpClient(TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            HttpClient client;
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                case Device.Android:
                    client = new HttpClient();
                    break;
                default:
                    client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip });
                    break;
            }

            client.Timeout = timeout;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            return client;
        }

        static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync<T>(HttpMethod httpMethod, string apiUrl, T requestData = default)
        {
            using (var httpRequestMessage = await GetHttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, apiUrl, requestData).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                try
                {
                    UpdateActivityIndicatorStatus(true);

                    return await Client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Report(e);
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    UpdateActivityIndicatorStatus(false);
                }
            }
        }

        static void UpdateActivityIndicatorStatus(bool isActivityIndicatorDisplayed)
        {
            if (isActivityIndicatorDisplayed)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Application.Current.MainPage.IsBusy = true);
                _networkIndicatorCount++;
            }
            else if (--_networkIndicatorCount <= 0)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Application.Current.MainPage.IsBusy = false);
                _networkIndicatorCount = 0;
            }
        }

        static async ValueTask<HttpRequestMessage> GetHttpRequestMessage<T>(HttpMethod method, string apiUrl, T requestData = default)
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(method, apiUrl);

            switch (requestData)
            {
                case T data when data.Equals(default(T)):
                    break;

                case Stream stream:
                    httpRequestMessage.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                    httpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                    break;

                default:
                    var stringPayload = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    break;
            }

            return httpRequestMessage;
        }

        static async Task<T> DeserializeResponse<T>(HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
        {
            httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            try
            {
                using (var contentStream = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(contentStream))
                using (var json = new JsonTextReader(reader))
                {
                    if (json is null)
                        return default;

                    return await Task.Run(() => Serializer.Deserialize<T>(json)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Report(e);
                throw;
            }
        }

        static void Report(Exception e, [CallerMemberName]string callerMemberName = "") => Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        #endregion
    }
}
```